# How can I lock an InnoDB table to prevent updates while that table is being copied?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I would like to temporarily lock a table to prevent other concurrent processes from making changes to it.  The reason for this is that this table is going to be copied to a temp table, altered, and then copied back (well original is actually dropped and new table is renamed).  Then after all this is complete, I want to unlock the table and hopefully have anything that was attempted during the lock resume.

I also need to be able to read from the table that has been locked to build the new table.

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't appear to work.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_PORT);

$mysqli->autocommit(false)

// create a table to hold parts to keep
$q1 = "CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE my_table;";
$res1 = $mysqli ->query($q1);       

// Lock table to avoid concurrent update issues
$q2 = "LOCK TABLE my_table WRITE;";
$res2 = $mysqli ->query($q2);           

// Insert data to keep into new table   
$q3 = "INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE some_id IN (SELECT ID FROM table2)";
$res3 = $mysqli ->query($q3);

// drop original table
$q4 = "DROP TABLE my_table;";
$res4 = $mysqli ->query($q4);

// rename new table
$q5 = "RENAME TABLE new_table TO my_table;";
$res5 = $mysqli ->query($q5);

$mysqli ->commit(); // commit changes and re-enable autocommit

$q = "UNLOCK TABLES;";
$res = $mysqli ->query($q);
```

To test, using PHPmyadmin, I've issued the "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0; LOCK TABLE my_table WRITE;" query and then tried to delete something from my_table and I was able to do so.  I want to block this.  Also, after issuing the lock statement, the rest of the procedure fails and nothing is altered.

Comment: "doesn't appear to work" What debugging have you performed?

Comment: I edited the question to let you know what is failing.  I just want to know the proper procedure for locking an INNODB table to prevent updates.

Comment: That's better. Have you checked permissions? Are you sure the deletion was immediately applied and not "queued"? Have you investigated whether turning auto-commit off is causing a problem? I've never found myself having to do that.

Comment: permissions are fine.  removing autocommit made no difference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry for the long answer, but this will need to be answered in multiple parts.

**1. On locking InnoDB tables with `LOCK TABLES` in general**

Using `LOCK TABLES` with InnoDB does in fact work, and can be demonstrated with two instances of the MySQL CLI connected to the same server (denoted by `mysql-1` and `mysql-2`) in the below example. It should generally be avoided in any sort of production context because of the impact to clients, but sometimes it can be the only option.

Create a table and populate it with some data:

```
mysql-1> create table a (id int not null primary key) engine=innodb;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql-1> insert into a (id) values (1), (2), (3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Lock the table:

```
mysql-1> lock tables a write;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Try to insert from `mysql-2`, which will hang waiting on the lock:

```
mysql-2> insert into a (id) values (4);
```

Now unlock the table from `mysql-1`:

```
mysql-1> unlock tables;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

And finally `mysql-2` unblocks and returns:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (6.30 sec)
```

**2. Using phpMyAdmin for testing**

Your testing method using phpMyAdmin is invalid because phpMyAdmin does not maintain a persistent connection to the server between queries from its web interface. In order to use any sort of locking `LOCK TABLES`, `START TRANSACTION`, etc., you need to maintain a connection while the locks are held.

**3. Locking all tables needed during work**

The way that MySQL locks tables, once you have used `LOCK TABLES` to explicitly lock anything, you will not be able to access any other tables that were not locked explicitly during the `LOCK` ... `UNLOCK` session. In your above example, you need to use:

```
LOCK TABLES my_table WRITE, new_table WRITE, table2 READ;
```

(I am assuming `table2` used in the subselect was not a typo.)

**4. Atomic table swap using `RENAME TABLE`**

Additionally, I should note that replacing the existing table using `DROP TABLE` followed by `RENAME TABLE` will cause a brief moment where the table does not exist, and this may confuse clients that expect it to exist. It is generally much better to do:

```
CREATE TABLE t_new (...);
<Populate t_new using some method>
RENAME TABLE t TO t_old, t_new TO t;
DROP TABLE t_old;
```

This will perform an atomic swap of the two tables.

Comment: My MySQL complains that I may not have locked tables when doing a RENAME. "Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction"
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Often you see simple answers for beginner questions upvoted 500+ times.
Then you see a great answer for a relevant good question upvoted only 9 times in 4 years!
Thanks, especially #4 was new to me and helped me solve a potential race condition.