# i need to get last inserted ids using create of eloquent or db::table's insert

Tags: php, laravel

Here's what I'm doing. I have a translation table, where There's only id column and nothing else. I need to bulk insert into this table. so here is how I do it.

```
$data=array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   array_push($data,array());
}
$s = DB::table("test")->insert($data);
```

but it returns boolean. What i want to get is the array of ids that got inserted. how do I achieve this?

Comment: you can use `insertGetId()` instead of the simple `insert`

https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-get-last-inserted-id-with-example

then you can cycle and create an array of the IDs

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is, it returns the last id. so i have to make the ids array myself. what If someone else inserts new records into this table?

Comment: Here go through this post and the comments. It makes sense

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065317/laravel-multi-insert-rows-and-retrieve-ids]

Comment: Maybe you can get the last existing ID before insertion, and get last ID after insertion, then you can infer the IDs in between.