# Laravel multiple records at once for single foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do insert multiple rows there are foreign keys in a table but it is not working.

**Table Sizes**

| id -> PK AI

| size_name

| size_price

**Table Stocks**

| id->PK AI

| pid-> FK

| size_id ->FK (Table size)

| qty

my controller looks like this:

**Controller**

```
    $sizes = new sizes;
    foreach($request->size as $key => $value)
    {
        $size[] = [
            'size_name' => $request->size[$key],
            'pid' => $lastid,
            'size_price' => $request->sizeprice[$key],
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ];
    }
    DB::table('sizes')->insert($size);
    $lastidsize = $sizes->id;

    $stocks = new stocks;
    foreach($request->stock as $key => $value)
    {
        $stock[] = [
            'pid' => $lastid,
            'size_id' => $lastidsize,
            'qty' => $request->stock[$key],
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ];
    }
    DB::table('stocks')->insert($stock);
```

**Error**

```
**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'size_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert 
into `stocks` (`created_at`, `pid`, `qty`, `size_id`) values (2021-01-24 11:40:50, 91, 1, ?), (2021- 
01-24 11:40:50, 91, 1, ?), (2021-01-24 11:40:50, 91, 1, ?))**
```

help please

Comment: `$sizes` doesn't have an 'id', so `null` ... it is a non existing model instance, it was never "saved" so it can't have an 'id'; so `$lastidsize` is `null`

Comment: @lagbox so i need to get foregin key from table sizes. could you fix me this code?

Comment: you are inserting multiple 'sizes' you only want the 'id' of the last one?

Comment: @lagbox yes you can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sizes has no id. You can use this function:

```
DB::table('sizes')->insertGetId($size);
```

also checkout these links for more help:
https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-insertgetid-multiple-rows-example

[Laravel - multi-insert rows and retrieve ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065317/laravel-multi-insert-rows-and-retrieve-ids)