# what is the alternative of insertGetId for multiple row insertion in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am inserting multiple rows in  table, And I need to get both row id to insert another table, I was using this query for single row :

```
    $ppfdata=[];

    foreach($request->package_type_id as $ppfkey => $ppfno){

        $ppfinput=[];

        $ppfinput['paid_amount'] = $post_data['package_price'][$ppfkey];
        $ppfinput['enroll_able'] = $post_data['enrollable'][$ppfkey];
        $ppfinput['user_id'] = $post_data['user_id'];
        $ppfinput['package_id'] = $post_data['package_id'][$ppfkey];
        $ppfinput['plan_id'] =  $post_data['plan_id'][$ppfkey];
        $ppfinput['status'] = $post_data['status'][$ppfkey];

        $ppfdata[]=$ppfinput;
    }

    $update_transections = DB::table('package_plan_fees')->insertGetId ($ppfdata);
```

What should I use for multiple rows ?

Comment: Loop, you should use loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - multi-insert rows and retrieve ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065317/laravel-multi-insert-rows-and-retrieve-ids)

Comment: @Justinas Sorry I given wrong code, please check the question again

Comment: Still loop. It does nothing more than two plain SQL queries: `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. And the last one can only be executed for latest query, not for N queries

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop over the items. You can do this:

```php
$ids = [];
foreach ($ppfdata as $item) {
    $ids[] = DB::table('package_plan_fees')->insertGetId($item);
}
```

Comment: This is true only if ID is single auto-increment field. If it's multi-column or e.g. `VARCHAR(64)`, it will not work. Also what if some other process inserts additional query between your queries?

Comment: @Justinas You are right about that fact, but since he has used it in the code we can assume that he has a working `insertGetId`.