# How to prevent MYSQL table for any updating independent of session?

Tags: mysql, database-design, locking

This is a follow up from [How can I lock an InnoDB table to prevent updates while that table is being copied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247803/how-can-i-lock-an-innodb-table-to-prevent-updates-while-that-table-is-being-copi). 
I want to lock a table and prevent any updation to it until lock is specifically removed by DB-admin.

**What I am trying to do?**

I have a table that store all possible values of degrees from -180 to +180. I have stored them in a table named `DEGREE_VALUES`. So, now there are 361 rows in the table. I do not want this table to be updated anyhow. I will just read the values from this table. I read [MySQL Reference for LOCK tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) but it says about client session. What I am looking for is independent of client session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not done via some sort of lock. Usually one would rather just revoke the update, delete and insert privileges from the users working with the table.

- read more about the `revoke` syntax in the [manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html)
- further down this [manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) you got a table with the different privileges

Comment: Eh?  Don't use `REVOKE` to do prevent access during an operation.

Comment: Who said anything about "during operation"? He just wants the table to never change again. The "lock tables" was just mentioned because he didn't know about the privileges thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM tbl FOR UPDATE;
copy the data
COMMIT;
```

The `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` prevents any other client from changing the table until the `COMMIT`.